# Center button in the carousel

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I am developing a personal project in a self-taught way to learn to work with HTML/CSS/Bootstrap 5. However, I'm having beginner's doubts. I'm trying to make the site responsive to work on mobile and tablet, but I'm failing to center the yellow button in the middle of the three bars representing the carousel slides. I've tried `margin auto;`, `text-align:center;` and `align-items: center;` but nothing seems to be working. How can I make the button always be in the center next to the three carousel bars when I change the screen dimensions?

[image]

```css
  
.buttonPosition {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  left: 41.5%;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.9em 1.4em;
  max-width: 40%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.carousel-item h5 {
  font-size: 48px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: rgb(185, 204, 240);
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
  bottom: 65%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.carousel-item p {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 1.9;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 124vh;
  min-height: 60px;
} 

.shadow {
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

.carousel-inner::before { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
  z-index: 1;
}

.active {
  color: rgb(14, 153, 100)!important;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="home" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="7500" data-bs-pause="false">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="./assets/images/plants.jpg" class="w-100" alt="plants">
      <h5 class="carousel-caption">Serviços de paisagismo profissionais</h5>
      <p class="shadow"> De manutenção de jardins a limpezas e reparações, temos paixão pelo nosso trabalho. Para orçamentos, basta entrar em contacto.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning mt-3 buttonPosition" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Contacta-nos <i class="uil uil-message button__icon"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="./assets/images/plant.jpg" class="w-100" alt="plant">
      <h5 class="carousel-caption">Estilo moderno e contemporâneo</h5>
      <p class="shadow">Deixe a arquitetura paisagista ser a razão do seu bem-estar. Trabalhamos no seu jardim com seriedade, profissionalismo, empenho e dedicação.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning mt-3 buttonPosition" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Contacta-nos <i class="uil uil-message button__icon"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="./assets/images/garden.jpg" class="w-100" alt="garden">
      <h5 class="carousel-caption">Simbiose entre um projeto e a sua qualidade de vida</h5>
      <p class="shadow">Cuidamos ao mais ínfimo detalhe de todos os espaços verdes, trazendo harmonia aliada ao nosso conhecimento e experiência.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning mt-3 buttonPosition" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Contacta-nos <i class="uil uil-message button__icon"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#home" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#home" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: just remove pos absolute, bottom and left. add `code`
    margin: auto;
    display: block!important;
`code`

Comment: @Dxg125 Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to do that, but when I put that code, the button disappears from the screen. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Same as from @hrystynaKb, there must be something other too, check out the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/umtfdxhn/
If this doesn't work on your side, you may want to check in developer console what affects your button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change  tag to actual  tag and wrap it into  tag. Then assign to a  `text-center` class.

So instead of this line:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning mt-3 buttonPosition" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Contacta-nos <i class="uil uil-message button__icon"></i></a>
```

Add this one:

```
<div class="text-center">
        <button href="#" class="btn btn-warning mt-3 text-center" data-bs-toggle="modal"
            data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Contacta-nos <i class="uil uil-message button__icon"></i></button>
</div>
```

And remove all position related styles from the `.buttonPosition` css rule (`position: absolute; bottom: 15%; left: 41.5%;`).

Also you may add `width: 100%` to `.carousel-indicators`, so those are properly centered as well. (just guessing, maybe you already have that, I am not sure because you didn't showed this part of the code).

Code snippet:

```css
.buttonPosition {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 30em;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.9em 1.4em;
  max-width: 40%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
    <link 
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <div id="home" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="7500" data-bs-pause="false">
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#home" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="./assets/images/plants.jpg" class="w-100" alt="plants">
          <h5 class="carousel-caption">Serviços de paisagismo profissionais</h5>
          <p class="shadow"> De manutenção de jardins a limpezas e reparações, temos paixão pelo nosso trabalho. Para orçamentos, basta entrar em contacto.</p>
          <div class="text-center">
        <button href="#" class=" buttonPosition btn btn-warning mt-3 text-center" data-bs-toggle="modal"
            data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Contacta-nos <i class="uil uil-message button__icon"></i></button>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="./assets/images/plant.jpg" class="w-100" alt="plant">
          <h5 class="carousel-caption">Estilo moderno e contemporâneo</h5>
          <p class="shadow">Deixe a arquitetura paisagista ser a razão do seu bem-estar. Trabalhamos no seu jardim com seriedade, profissionalismo, empenho e dedicação.</p>
          <div class="text-center">
        <button href="#" class="btn btn-warning mt-3 text-center" data-bs-toggle="modal"
            data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Contacta-nos <i class="uil uil-message button__icon"></i></button>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="./assets/images/garden.jpg" class="w-100" alt="garden">
          <h5 class="carousel-caption">Simbiose entre um projeto e a sua qualidade de vida</h5>
          <p class="shadow">Cuidamos ao mais ínfimo detalhe de todos os espaços verdes, trazendo harmonia aliada ao nosso conhecimento e experiência.</p>
          <div class="text-center">
        <button href="#" class="btn btn-warning mt-3 text-center" data-bs-toggle="modal"
            data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Contacta-nos <i class="uil uil-message button__icon"></i></button>
</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#home" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#home" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to do that, but when I put that code, the button disappears from the screen.  Is there any other solution? I have commented out the following code: ```position: absolute; bottom: 15%; left: 41.5%;``` and added the ```text-center```.

Comment: You button, is not an actual button element, it is <a> element. So you need to change that. Then you need to wrap your button element into a div. And assign to this div `text-center` class. (and remove all properties you have listed above from the css rule .buttonPosition.

I will edit my answer to provide you with more context.

Comment: Thank you for editing the reply. I tried putting the code you posted, but the button keeps disappearing from the carousel slide. I don't understand why it disappears. I already put the button wrapped in a div with the ```text-center``` class as you suggested, but it's not working.

Comment: I have added edits that I have suggested above to the code snipped, and pasted edited code snippet to my answer, if you will click "run code snippet", you can see that button is centered and aligned. So if you will compare my edited code to your code and everything is the same, but still do not work, probably some other styles that you didn't attach to this question are overriding the button behaviour.

Comment: I have added to the post all the css classes that are used in the carousel. There are some that I didn't put because they are imported directly from Bootstrap 5. I tried to use your code but the button disappears. Maybe it's because there is some class that conflicts. Can you tell me which class I have to change to make it work please?

Comment: I have updated the `buttonPosition` class in my aswer, please paste that in you code. Also note that you should add `buttonPosition` class to your buttons class list:
 `<button href="#" class=" buttonPosition btn btn-warning mt-3 text-center" data-bs-toggle="modal"
            data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Contacta-nos <i class="uil uil-message button__icon"></i></button>`

Comment: Thank you so much! I put positive vote on your answer. :)